# What exactly is SSD_ResNet50_v1_FPN?

Tags: tensorflow, feature-extraction, object-detection-api, retinanet

In the TensorFlow Models Zoo, the object detection has a few popular single shot object detection models named "retinanet/resnet50_v1_fpn_ ..." or "Retinanet (SSD with Resnet 50 v1)". The paper usually linked to these works is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002) but the paper presents a different model, Detectron. So I understand SSD_ResNet50 FPN" uses the FPN feature extraction concept from that paper but are there any other more detailed documentation avaliable to understand how SSD integrates with FPN exactly? And what is the exact model architecture for this TF zoo Model?